# PIR sensor GPIO

Tags: pi-2, rpi.gpio

[CIrcuit1[image: ][1]]By default PIR input pin(middle) is HIGH. When i run the below code, gp.input(27) always gives me value 1.

My code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as gp
import time
gp.setmode(gp.BCM)
gp.setup(2, gp.OUT)
gp.setup(27, gp.IN)
print "LED is ON"
gp.output(2, gp.HIGH)
i = gp.input(27)
print i

while True:
                  if gp.input(27):
                                      print "motion detected"
                                      gp.output(2, gp.LOW)
                 else:
                           print "No motion detected"
                           time.sleep(1)
```

OutPut:
LED is ON
1
motion detected

Kindly let me know if i have done any mistake in code. Plz find the circuit i have used in attachment.

Comment: There is no attachment

Comment: While waiting for the missing circuit attachment, I'm wondering if you have a pin 27 pulled to ground by a resistor (e.g., a 10K one).

Comment: Most PIR devices send pulses (one or more) and don't leave the line low for long.  You might need to use wait_for_edge instead.  Plus they are fairly susceptible to EM interference, so careful if you have wifi plugged in...

Comment: Hi , Can you explain me bit clear about wait_for_edge concept